pdf/a export no longer an option in mac os 14.x - what are the options for mac users?
It appears that the option to save a pdf as pdf/a compliant has disappeared in Mac OS 14.6. How do I get pdf/a output back?
Update: The option to select pdf/a has disappeared from all print to pdf dialogues - which is why I initially didn't name a specific text editing software. I was previously able to select pdf/a output from TextEdit or Pages to name two.

What application did you use to provide pdf/a that now no longer appears to work? It would help if you provide a few more details of your workflow.

In Preview, if you use File > Export, (as opposed to File > Export As PDF), then the options are there.


Thanks, Ben! Yup, the pdf/a option was in Preview.
